Issues Regarding GetPivotData Autofill in Microsoft Excel
I'm new to excel, and I'm attempting to reference a cell in a pivot table with a GETPIVOTDATA() function but excel won't autofill as every reference I've found has said(my references end up being "=D4", instead of the full formula, for example). Is there a way to fix this?
For context, I'm using the online version of Excel on Microsoft 365. I'm not sure if the version is relevant, but a source I found was using an older version.
EDIT: I'm attempting to reference a formula like
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sale Amount",'pivot table 1-2'!$A$3,"Resort","Logan Hills")

but I am instead getting references like (='pivot table 1-2'!A3).

What exact formula are you using? (edit it into your question :)

What is the formula you have used for GETPIVOTDATA() like this? --> =GETPIVOTDATA("Sales",D4) the text can be anything within the quotes based on your pivot table. if its showing the formula then may be the cells are formatted as text. you need to check that, in the Home Ribbon Tab --> Under Group Number see whether its showing Text or General

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bO6DpBq5OLwzIMUIB3WwfiUMyp_lxJKE/view?usp=sharing
I'm attaching this link for context as well. The issue is how Excel won't automatically generate a GETPIVOTDATA formula when I click on a cell in a pivottable

No not that way. The formula will be: =GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Sale Amount",'pivot table 1-2'!$C$4,"Resot","Logan Hills")  need to specify the data field as is, btw the downvote is not from my end. And the reason one who downvoted could be because if you read the MSFT Documentation you can find it. I will try find a duplicate post to tag it

See this post, although it uses INDIRECT() function to reference the sheet name directly, but in your example it will be hardcoded. Example

Is there a means of generating the formula automatically? I'll need to repeat this process across many different pivot tables, and typing the formula manually for each section would take much longer.

You will certainly need to make some changes, so you can refer cells with conditions to pull the data from pivot table. You will need to research more for that. Also this looks like some home assignment, you will need to follow the instructions given in the module, it will help you to learn.

Thanks for the insight, but the directions are simply "type an '=' and click on the value in the pivottable". I've attempted this and all other online references say to do this, but the video I've linked shows that my results are different

If its already mentioned to use = then you need to follow that only.
